# null pointer whith networkinformation cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I have the below error message when I deactivate mobile data in the settings section. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance !

**Crash Log**

```
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862): Uncaught exception from plugin
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager.getConnectionInfo(NetworkManager.java:201)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager.execute(NetworkManager.java:133)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:227)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:738)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-04 13:14:45.569: E/PluginManager(23862):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000010 (has extras) } in org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager$1@4181a808
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager.getConnectionInfo(NetworkManager.java:201)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager.updateConnectionInfo(NetworkManager.java:171)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager.access$0(NetworkManager.java:168)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager$1.onReceive(NetworkManager.java:110)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
06-04 13:14:45.589: E/AndroidRuntime(23862):    ... 9 more
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

this is code of my application

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>myapp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div id="deviceready">
                <p class="event listening"></p>
                <p class="event received"></p>
                <p id="connexion"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

            //listener qui se déclenche dès que le mobile est prêt
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady , false);


            function onDeviceReady() {
                try{
                    checkConnection();
                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }


            function checkConnection() {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'connexion de type inconnu';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'connexion Ethernet';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'connexion WiFi';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'connexion 2G';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'connexion 3G';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'connexion 4G';
                states[Connection.CELL]     = 'connexion generique';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'pas de connexion internet';

            document.getElementById('connexion').innerHTML='type de la connexion internet : ' +states[networkState];
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO) ! Questions on SO are in english / J'ai traduit ta question en anglais, personne ne répondra sur une question en français ;) Peux tu ajouter le code qui produit cette erreur / Can you add the code that causes this problem ? Merci/Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plugin problem.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6907

Just run

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.network-information
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
```

like MazzCris suggested

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this solved the problem for me:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.network-information

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Comment: seems to be a plugin problem. After installing the current plugin version (-dev version) the exception disappeared

Answer (score 0):

It took me a whole day to fix this issue. What i did was, replace the **NetworkManager.java** with same file in an old project which was working.
Now its not crashing when the app is offline.